# Do something if a variable is defined

Tags: javascript

In JS, I want to do something if a variable is defined or not. I was under the impression this syntax would work:

```
if (foo) {
    console.log('foo is defined');
} else {
    console.log('foo is not defined');       
}
```

But I get a "Uncaught Reference Error: foo is not defined":

http://jsfiddle.net/cfUss/

Am I missing something? I thought this was very basic js and had used this syntax a ton before.

Comment: `if( typeof foo === "undefined")`

Comment: What do you mean by "if a variable exists"? It's likely to be an XY-problem.

Comment: @zerkms - fixed "exists" to "undefined or not"

Comment: A duplicate of so, so many questions.

Comment: @Donny P: looking at your jsfiddle - how is it possible that in your code you're trying to work with a variable that isn't defined? Never happened to me. There is a chance you're doing something conceptually wrong.

Comment: @zerkms somebody wrote a function that does that check. Apparently they didnt realize it was coupled to a scope where their variable was defined.

Comment: @Donny P: "somebody wrote a function" vs "I want to do something if a variable is defined or not"... uhm, sorry, I'm lost. But anyway, what you're asking about just should never occur in a real code. PS: if the given code relies to a variable defined in another scope - then it's semantic not to check whether a variable was defined or not, but to check if it's truthy or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two related concepts, being declared and being defined. Trying to reference a name which is not declared is what throws the error, not trying to reference a value which is undefined.

So for example:

```
var foo; //Declare the variable. It's still not defined however
if (foo) {
    console.log('foo is defined');
} else {
    console.log('foo is not defined');       
}
```

Of course, if I actually want to detect something which is undeclared or undefined as you mention you want to do, I usually prefer to be more explicit and use `if(typeof foo != "undefined")` since `var foo; if (foo)` doesn't trigger for defined but falsey values. Finally, you can do direct comparison to an undefined value if you want to test whether something is undefined and allow it to throw if undeclared, e.g. `if(foo !== void(0))`

Comment: Your use of "defined" would be better as "initialised". For many, a declared variable is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Check its [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
if (typeof(foo) != 'undefined')
```

Your check only works if the variable is declared and [falsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/), but you need to know if the object is even *defined*.

Comment: Thanks Igor, but then shouldn't the answers to this question be incorrect? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686001/javascript-check-if-object-property-exists-even-when-object-is-undefined

Comment: @Donny P: that answer is completely irrelevant to yours current (badly worded) question.

Comment: @zerkms, they're both trying to do something if a variable is defined or not. I fixed the wording in my question. politeness appreciated

Comment: @DonnyP Yeah I mean they're not *wrong*, but if the variable literally doesn't exist (rather than just being null, for example), that approach won't work.

Comment: @Donny P: 1. they are not 2. There is difference between doing that for a variable and for an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof foo == "undefined") {
     console.log('doesnt exist');  
} else {
     console.log('it exists');   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cfUss/2/

Comment: The *typeof* operator tells you the Type of a variable's value, not whether it exists or not. Unfortunately it also returns *undefined* if the variable doesn't exist, so by itself it doesn't tell you if the variable has been created or not (i.e. whether it "exists").