# javascript - check if object parameter is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation similar with the one here: [Javascript check if object property exists, even when object is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686001/javascript-check-if-object-property-exists-even-when-object-is-undefined).

My problem is, what happens if you have a chain of properties. Example:

```
var obj = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 'I exists'}}}}
```

I need to check if 'd' is defined. In order to not get an error, I would have to check like:

```
if (typeof obj != 'undefined' && typeof obj['a'] != 'undefined' && typeof obj['a']['b'] != 'undefined' && typeof obj['a']['b']['c'] != 'undefined' && typeof obj['a']['b']['c']['d'] != 'undefined')
```

You can see how this can get annoying. Extrapolate to a level 999 deep element for example. Is there any way to get rid of the first n-1 conditions?

Comment: You could surround your `obj.a.b.c.d !== 'undefined'` statement with a `try ... catch` block. Like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ds73tp0/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with try-catch:

```js
var check = function(obj) {
  try {
    return (typeof obj.a.b.c.d !== 'undefined');
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};

alert(check({
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'c': {
        'd': 'I exists'
      }
    }
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value for truthy as follow.

You can't get rid of the first `n - 1` conditions but you can shorten your statement

```
if (obj && obj.a && obj.a.b && obj.a.b.c && typeof obj.a.b.c.d !== 'undefined')
    // Use of obj.a.b.c.d is considered safe here
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32886078/3296661) said in his answer:

> You can't get rid of the first `n - 1` conditions

So you will just have to shorten your statement, so it's not as long.

Check this following example i've created:

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3orpwhq7/4/)

```
var obj = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 'I exists'}}}};

for (var key in obj)
{
    if (obj && obj.a.b.c.d) 
    { 
        console.log(obj.a.b.c.d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
function checkUndefined(obj) {
  var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(x[i])) {
      return false;
    }
    obj = obj[x[i]];
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Was thinking about something similar, hoped I would not need it :).

Comment: You can try to use Tushar's answer as well.

Comment: True, I upvoted it, but that shortens the problem to a certain degree... an object parse solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your own property checker like next one:

JavaScript:

```
function test(object) {
    var restOfKeys = [];
    for (var _i = 1; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        restOfKeys[_i - 1] = arguments[_i];
    }
    var propertyToTest;
    if (object === undefined || !restOfKeys.length) {
        return false;
    }
    propertyToTest = restOfKeys.shift();
    if (restOfKeys.length) {
        return test.apply(void 0, [object[propertyToTest]].concat(restOfKeys));
    }
    return object[propertyToTest] !== undefined;
}
var toTest = { a: { b: { c: "asd" } } };
alert(test(toTest, "a", "b", "c"));
```

TypeScript:

```
function test(object: any, ...restOfKeys: string[]) {
    let propertyToTest: string;

    if (object === undefined || !restOfKeys.length) {
        return false;
    }

    propertyToTest = restOfKeys.shift();

    if (restOfKeys.length) {
        return test(object[propertyToTest], ...restOfKeys);
    }

    return object[propertyToTest] !== undefined;
}


var toTest = { a: { b: { c: "asd" } } };

alert(test(toTest, "a", "b", "c"));
```

Source Code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20test(object%3A%20any%2C%20...restOfKeys%3A%20string%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%09let%20propertyToTest%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09if%20(object%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%7C%7C%20!restOfKeys.length)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20false%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20propertyToTest%20%3D%20restOfKeys.shift()%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09if%20(restOfKeys.length)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20test(object%5BpropertyToTest%5D%2C%20...restOfKeys)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09return%20object%5BpropertyToTest%5D%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20toTest%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20%7B%20c%3A%20%22asd%22%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(test(toTest%2C%20%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20%22c%22))%3B)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {a:undefined,b:undefined,c:undefined,d:'I exists'};
  if(typeof obj['a'] === 'object'){alert(typeof obj['a']);}
  else if(typeof obj['b'] === 'object'){alert(typeof obj['b']);}
  else if(typeof obj['c'] === 'object'){alert(typeof obj['c']);}
  else{alert(typeof obj['d']+' : '+obj['d']);}
```

check here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp for datatype
and here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp for array.